# Show specific column by ID in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, show, records

I have problem (i think for you is simple to solve) with PHP and MySQL.
I have database, that call "tekst".
There is 3 column:

1. id (autoincrement),
2. date (timestamp),
3. tresc (text)

and the site: index.html.
I want to paste code like that `<?php echo "$id1"; ?>` into index.html to display a column "treść" assigned to some "id".

Now I do like that:

`$w = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tekst WHERE id=5"));`

`echo $w['tresc'];`

but when I have many records, it will be troublesome.

How to create MySQL Query to display what i want ?
In one page i will have many ID's.

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mysql_fetch_row`.

**example**

```
mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tekst WHERE id=1"));
```

#### [`Official Document`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tekst");

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $r['tresc'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use PDO or MySQLi as those mysql_ functions are deprecated.

And then, to list all the ids, use a different query:`SELECT * FROM tekst`

Which will return an array you should iterate.